# How create record in HABTM Rails Association How make this?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I'm having some trouble creating a new relation in my `has_and_belongs_to_many` model. I defined the models like this:

```
journals model

  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts

post model

  has_and_belongs_to_many :journal
```

I don't know how create the association , I made a button but I don't know how it works. I created the action `add_post`

```
  def add_post
    @journal_post = JournalsPosts.new
  end
```

I make this link to create the association but I don't know what I have to do now:

```
<%= link_to "Add to Journal",:controller => "journals",:action => "add_post" %>
```

The redirect works correctly but I don't know how to proceed now ? Do you know about some guide to HABTM associations? I have already tried [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#choosing-between-has_many-through-and-has_and_belongs_to_many), but it didn't help.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

You should highly consider using `has_many, :through` as that's the preferred way to do these kinds of relationships now in Rails.

That said, if you want to continue with `has_and_belongs_to_many`, you need to somehow get the journal and post ids that you want to associate so you can correctly create the association.

In your routes:

```
resources :journals do
  member do
    put :add_post
  end
end
```

In your view (make sure you set `@journal` and `@post` somewhere):

`<%= link_to "Add to Journal", add_post_journal_path(@journal, :post_id => @post.id), :method => :put %>`

In your controller:

```
def add_post
  @journals_posts = JournalsPosts.new(:journal_id => params[:id], :post_id => params[:post_id])

  if @journals_posts.save
    ...
  else
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: I realize the OP has "JournalsPosts" but that model wouldn't even exist, nor should it, with a habtm relationship.

Answer (score 16):

After researching this myself, you should be able to do

```
def add_post
    j = Journal.first # or find_by, etc
    p = Post.first # or find_by, etc
    j.posts << p # creates a record in journals_posts table
    j.save!
end
```

(1) The accepted answer made it sound as though the association could only be made directly.  Also you wouldn't have a "JournalsPosts" class if you're using the habtm association, since it specifically avoids using a model for the intermediary table.

(2) Note that this association will not be unique.  If you call this multiple times, you'll get multiple entries in the journals_posts table with the same two integer pairs.

Comment: You don't need `j.save!`